# Magical academy book where the female main character bonds with a mythological wolf/fox, it was a clean YA book

Tags: story-identification, books

A while ago I read a book that was set at a magical academy. The female main character goes there and she didn't know that she had magical powers.

I remember that in the book there were doors that led to different rooms/places. One of the places was a beach that no one entered because there was a magical creature that was a wolf/fox type animal that everyone was scared of, but this creature bonded with the female main character and it became her familiar.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When and where did you read this?  Do you remember the cover art?

Comment: Hi I read this about a year ago and I've been searching for the last couple of months but I can't find it. I don't remember what the cover art looked like but I remember that it was the first book of the series, sorry if that's not helpful

Comment: Superficially like [Gunnerkrigg Court](https://www.amazon.com/Gunnerkrigg-Court/dp/184856175X)

Comment: The description reminds me of [Gunnerkrigg Court](https://www.gunnerkrigg.com/).  (Which is a bit easier to look at than @FuzzyBoots's.)

Comment: Hi thank you for the recommendation but it was definitely a book rather than a comic, it's driving me insane not being able to find it lol